# Does the IP header have a "Padding" field?

Tags: ip, ipv4, layer3

I found two images of the IP header, one image shows a field called "Padding", while the other image don't show the "Padding" field:

[image]

[image]

Which one of these two images is correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Padding is only used if there are options that are not an even 32 bits. The whole header must be divisible by 32 bits. *[RFC 791, Internet Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791.html)* has the official header:

> [3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc791.html#section-3.1).
> Internet Header Format
>
> A summary of the contents of the internet header follows:
>
> ```
>  0                   1                   2                   3
>  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |Version|  IHL  |Type of Service|          Total Length         |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |         Identification        |Flags|      Fragment Offset    |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |  Time to Live |    Protocol   |         Header Checksum       |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                       Source Address                          |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                    Destination Address                        |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
> |                    Options                    |    Padding    |
> +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>
>                  Example Internet Datagram Header
>
>                             Figure 4.
> ```

In essence, both of your diagrams are correct. It is just that the second does not distinguish between the options and padding for the options.

> Padding: variable
>
> The internet header padding is used to ensure that the internet header
> ends on a 32 bit boundary. The padding is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is used to make sure that the IP datagram is of required minimum length. There is no seperate padding field as such in n the IP header. 2nd diagram is more appropriate.

Comment: I'd say the second is more appropriate for someone concerned only with the content of the header.  The first is more appropriate for someone concerned with the transmission and reception of the header.